# Does a KN95 that says 'non medical' helps to protect against COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, face-mask-respirator, personal-protective-equipment, protection, regulatory-agencies

I saw this type of face masks on a 'building tools' store (like home depot), and on the label said, among other things in chinese and english,   *non medical*.

In this [KN95 Masks Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AldzhSzHEZ0) mentions

> These masks, like NIOSH N95 masks, provide protection from 95% of particles that are greater than .3 microns in diameter.

However do they also protect even when says *non medical*?

**Update**

I've got one and as you can see the only difference with a medical mask is the FDA label (notice the upper RHS, there is none), as pointed out by @BobE. The brand is exactly the same.

[image]

inside the cover was this paper

[image]

Here is the pic with the FDA label (notice the upper RHS, the FDA label)

[image]

Comment: Any mask is certainly better than no mask.

Comment: @user253751 In general yes, however a mask made by vacuum bag filters can irritate lungs, as said by [LangLangC's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/47430/53862) on Skeptics

Comment: It probably should be noted, no mask protects "against" COVID-19. It protects others from you potentially spreading COVID-19 by spitting unwittingly or sneezing on others - which is a difference. The better the mask, the less likely you are to unwittingly transmit COVID-19 - not the less likely you are to contract COVID-19. This also means, you don't need to ride around in your car by yourself while wearing a mask. ;)

Comment: @SnakeDoc That is incorrect. Studies are accumulating which show that masks have a protective effect *for the wearer* as well: https://www.npr.org/2020/07/20/893227088/growing-body-of-evidence-suggests-masks-protect-those-wearing-them-too
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/27/health/coronavirus-mask-protection.html

Comment: Those are dubious studies at best. They seem to see an increase in asymptomatic individuals when wearing masks, which defies logic (still getting the virus, but not showing symptoms, simply because you had a cloth in front of your face?). Neither source said it was ready to make the claim of two-way protection either. So... my statement stands. Don't wear it in your house or in your car by yourself. Do wear it in public when you're around others.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, evidence is accumulating showing that the smaller the initial dose, the more likely it is that you'll have an asymptomatic infection.

Comment: Worth noting that this manufacturer has been tested (albeit not extensively) by the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npptl/respirators/testing/NonNIOSHresults.html) and was found to have a filtration efficiency between 98% and 89%.

Comment: @Geoffrey ooh indeed very worth noting, thanks.

Comment: @Mark We'll have to see. There's a lot of made-up "boogey-man" things coming out about this virus... things that are extremely unlikely such as transmission to animals and then back again, catching the virus multiple times, it lives on surfaces for 6 hours, scratch that, 6 days, and more. Having some NPR article stating some research shows something is pretty useless. We'll talk once it's proven.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Still wearing a mask in your car? Feeling like a fool yet?

Comment: @SnakeDoc are all Trump supporters as dumb as you?

Comment: @LawnmowerMan I guess that confirms it. Salty and bitter, doesn't want to admit you were had good and plenty. Probably wore a mask inside your own house too I bet. What a fool.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Why are you even here? Isn't there a bridge you are supposed to be hiding under? Is trolling SE the only way to obtain validation in your life? Do you not have the respect of your peers and coworkers? No social life? I'd recommend a dating site. Finding a romantic partner will do wonders for your non-existent social skills. I know you think you are being clever and that you're obviously right, but every crank thinks that because they are trapped in a box of their own psychic construction. I feel sorry for you. You have all of my pity, every last drop.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Sorry you're so upset about falling for yet another bogus "initial study"... you probably have a tough time navigating life in general if you fall for things like "only getting a small dose means you have less severe symptoms!". Viruses don't work like that... but paranoid you falls hook, line and sinker all the way to the bottom every time. Driving around by yourself wearing a mask... you must have looked really foolish to everyone you drove by. Yet, you claim to be the smart one? Please... time go back and brush up on your high school biology. Or continue to act the fool...

Comment: I dunno why you are fixated with me. But I'll try to spell this out in a way that makes sense to your obviously limited cognitive faculties. 1. You have presented 0 evidence in favor of your position. 2. You expect me and others to accept your facts as authoritative, despite your utter lack of credentials. 3. Didn't you see the news reports that your fuhrer lied to you about the dangers of covid way back in Feb? I guess you didn't get the memo. 4. None of your comments contribute to this discussion and prove that this SE has no moderation. 5. You dum dum poopy head!! Hope you understand now.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan It is you, which needs to provide evidence to support your position... cuz, out here in the real world, it doesn't exist. Basically, you're tired of being the fool driving around by themselves in an empty car while wearing a mask, and now you're too afraid to admit you were wrong, so you have to continue with this charade? Seems very logical... not.

Comment: I read somewhere that the KN95 medical have special treatment on the surface (protection against blood/liquid) vs KN95 non medical masks - not sure if that is the only difference in quality

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the US, in order for a mask to be labeled "medical", that mask must be approved by the FDA as a medical device. With so many new people manufacturing masks coupled with the public demand for masks, it is likely not profitable to delay to seek FDA approval. The FDA also is unlikely to approve a new manufacturer's mask without ASTM testing.

Thus, it is possible that these KN95 masks are a functional equivalent to N95 masks approved for medical use, but have not yet been approved by FDA.

Keep in mind that that coronavirus particles (fancy scientific name “virions”) are spheres with diameters of approximately 0.125 microns (125 nm). The smallest particles are 0.06 microns, and the largest are 0.14 microns. (Lancet)

The [article here](https://smartairfilters.com/en/blog/can-masks-capture-coronavirus/) may be useful to help you sort through the efficiency of masks.

Comment: When reminding about the size of the virions, in comparison to the reference particle size for the masks, it should be mentioned that 0.3 is the size where the filters are the least efficient. Smaller particles, especially below 0.1 microns are filtered more efficiently due to the diffusion capture mechanism. Comparing with tests that used 0.007 micron particles is just pure nonsense. The filters do not act as a sieve. Cf., eg., Fig 4 in https://www.tsi.com/getmedia/4982cf03-ea99-4d0f-a660-42b24aedba14/ITI-041-A4?ext=.pdf

Comment: In addition, KN95 masks don't seal as well as N95 masks, because they just loop around the ears rather than having multiple straps around the head: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0075/2192/7257/files/Comparison_FFP2_KN95_N95_Filtering_Facepiece_Respirator_Classes.pdf

Comment: Note also that when the virus is expelled from the body, it rarely is alone. It's usually attached to some water or cells as it was expelled from a person's nose or mouth. Consequently, the effective size of the particles that need to be filtered are much larger that the size of the virus, >= 1 micron https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/factcheck/2020/06/11/fact-check-n-95-filters-not-too-large-stop-covid-19-particles/5343537002/

Answer (score 3):

Typically for an N95 mask to be considered "medical grade" it must be compatible with a sterile environment, such as by filtering both inhaled and exhaled air.

Surgical masks provide some filtration of exhaled air, which is why they're useful in surgury (e.g. keep saliva off an operating region).
I have an N95 mask advertised for environments with dust and smoke (e.g. to wear while working with soil to [prevent Legionnaires' disease](https://worksafe.govt.nz/topic-and-industry/legionnaires-disease/legionnaires-disease-and-legionellosis/)). In these environments there's no need to filter air on the exhale; such filter would add to cost and increase the effort to exhale. For this reason "medical grade" N95 masks may be more expensive and more humid than those with a valve for exhaling air.

Unless there's a significant difference in how the filters are manufactured, then these masks are effectively the same for filtration of inhaled air. If medical grade masks were able to filter 99% of particles within a given size range then they would be N99 masks, not N95 masks.

However as @BobE mentioned "medical grade" likely must pass further tests and conform to other regulations (and perhaps requiring more expensive quality control measures) which would drive up the prices and could delay a product from reaching market.

Comment: Though a big point of wearing a mask against Covid-19 is filtration of exhaled air, to not infect others.

Answer (score 1):

The mask protects people from **the person wearing the mask**.  In surgery, my colleagues and I wear a mask to protect the patient's open wound from me.  Do not make the mistake of thinking that you, as the mask wearer, are conferring a degree of protection that provides safety.

Comment: The evidence says otherwise:
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/27/health/coronavirus-mask-protection.html
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23498357/
https://ucsf.app.box.com/s/blvolkp5z0mydzd82rjks4wyleagt036
https://www.oregonlive.com/coronavirus/2020/06/big-coronavirus-outbreak-at-newport-seafood-plants-is-contained-health-authorities-say.html